# Is it possible to build a BB10 library which uses Qt classes

Tags: shared-libraries, static-libraries, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I'm looking into making some reusable components for use with BB10 Cascades apps. I can create static and shared libraries from the IDE's new project wizard, selecting shared/static library as the project type with basic functionality (such as a "Calculator" library) but would like to know if it's possible to use Qt/Cascades objects, even something as simple as QString would be good to start off with.

I don't create many libraries so excuse me if this seems overly simple. There are [some guides](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Cascades-Development-Knowledge/How-to-create-a-shared-or-static-library-to-be-used-in-other/ta-p/1886233) on how to do what I'm after but they're all a bit out of date. One of the suggestions it to create a regular cascades project and alter the .pro file, but the entries to alter don't exist when creating a project with the current IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is. The real question is what is the easiest/best procedure? I came up with a way to do this with very [early versions of Momentics](http://www.hrbuckley.net/2012/08/bb10-ndk-creating-and-using-static.html), but it is way out of date now. The only value in that Blog post now is the link to a [support forums post](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Cascades-Development/Library-projects-in-Cascades/m-p/1891995#M2899). Sadly I'm not sure how up to date that post is either.

I haven't built any libraries with Qt classes for my current projects, but as the UI design settles down I do intend to do so. Have a read through those two links. If they don't help, let me know ad I'll see if I can free up some time to have another look at it sooner. Unless someone else gets there first.

EDIT (Again):

I decided to completely rewrite the procedure on my blog.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Your blog was probably overkill for my needs right now, but it's definitely worth a bookmark. The support forum post was basically pretty much what I ended up doing, with some minor changes need for the latest IDE such as there is no TEMPLATE = app line, so you just need to add TEMPLATE = lib

Comment: Not to worry. I wrote, and re-wrote it so I can remember how to do it. Just as easy to make it avalable for anyone else who wants it.